# Flask integration with Dash App - routing / 404 Not found error

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login, werkzeug

I am using flask' login module with my dash app and need to integrate dash app in Flask environment. I am using flask for authentication and have added a navigation menu that links to the dash app.

Here's my file structure:

- auth

  - login
  - server
  - init.py
- templates

  - base.html
- pages

  - home.py
  - page2.py

index.py
app.py

contents of `app.py`

```
import dash
import flask

app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                          external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,
               )

server = app.server
```

contents of `index.py`

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # header
    html.Div([
        
        dcc.Link(
            href=get_relative_path('/home'),
        ),

        dcc.Link(
            href=get_relative_path('/archive'),
        ),

        dcc.Location(id='url'),

        html.Div(id='page-content', style={'margin-left': '2%'}),

])



# Render page content
@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"),
              [
                Input('url', 'pathname')
              ]
             )
def display_content(pathname):

    if pathname == '/home':
        return home.layout

    elif pathname == '/archive':
        return archive.layout()
        
    else:
        return home.layout
```

contents of `init.py`

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required
from .server import server
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from index import app as dashApp


@server.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def render_dashboard():
    return redirect('/dashboard/')


app = DispatcherMiddleware(server, {
    '/dashboard': dashApp.server,
    #add dash routes
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5000, app, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

contents of `server.py`

```
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
```

When I attempt to navigate / click the link to dash app, I get a 404 Not Found error. For some reason, upon debugging it seems that the `def display_content` function in `index.py` is not running and app / page layout isn't rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Can you append a trailing slash at the end of the route.

```
@server.route('/dashboard/')
```